# Engine issues raised tac

Tags: engine

My wife has a 2015 Chevy Cruise and the tac is raised up a little bit from where it used to sit. Can it just need a tuneup?

Comment: Increase related to fall in temperature?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  What did the tach used to read when idling and what does it read now?  Are you running the A/C or the DEFROST?